# Image on select show on img-src holder and/or from API server data - Ionic 3, Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So, I have a html tag like this `<img [src]="imageUrl"/>`. This simply shows an image once selected from the gallery or camera but not the one present in database. And if I use `<img src="{{profile.photo}}"/>` then I can see image stored in the database but not the one selected from gallery or camera.

I am not sure how to have both functionality working. currently I am using these `<img src="{{profile.photo}}"/>` but what I want is a combination of both.

```
               `<img [src]="{{ imageUrl | profile.photo}}"/>`
```

so, what I want to achieve is when page loads show image present inside database but when user selects new photo, replace the photo from

Comment: Can you show the `ts` code also?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
  <img  src={{myImage}}/>
```

where `myImage` is set to database stored image for the start. When the user selects a new photo, change its value to the url.

Comment: I cant do that. I am passing base64 everywhere.